# How can I traverse to a particular element using xpath from a particular node?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Assume the following DOM fragment:

```
    <div id="ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR" class="search_options_menucontentbg" style="z-index: 999999; display: block;">
    <div id="glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR">
    <a id="closebtn" class="close-btn close" href="#">X</a>
    <table id="citydropdown" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="700">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <tr>
           <td class="leftbg"/>
           <td class="mapbg">
              <div class="btnrow">
                 <div class="heading"/>
                 <div class="search_options_menucontent" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                    <div id="dropdownGroup1">
                       <h3 class="title1">India</h3>
                       <div class="dropdownDiv">
                       <ul>
                          <li class="city_selected ">
                             <a class="" value="IXB" text="Bagdogra (IXB)" onclick="javascript:$CityDropDown.SetSelectedValue(this);return false;" tooltip="" href="#"> Bagdogra (IXB)</a>
                         </li>
                         <li class="">
                            <a class="" value="BLR" text="Bengaluru (BLR)" onclick="javascript:$CityDropDown.SetSelectedValue(this);return false;" tooltip="" href="#"> Bengaluru (BLR)</a>
                         </li>
                         <li class="">
                           <a class="" value="MAA" text="Chennai (MAA)" onclick="javascript:$CityDropDown.SetSelectedValue(this);return false;" tooltip="" href="#"> Chennai (MAA)</a>
```

How do I traverse from node starting with `<div id="ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR"` to `<a class="" value="IXB" text="Bagdogra (IXB)"`?

Comment: just and additional note-I want to traverse from node starting from <div id="ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR" to a web element-
<a class="" value="IXB" text="Bagdogra (IXB)"

Comment: Please provide your output element. Which you wanted to find.

Comment: Please provide some information, and a question. What element are you wanting to traverse to from which element? The more information you provide the better answer you will get.

Answer (score 1):

First off, either you mistyped the HTML or the HTML is malformed -- note the two consecutive `<tr>` tags.

That aside, rather than answer the question, I suggest you look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139402/how-to-select-following-sibling-xml-tag-using-xpath) on using sibling operators in XPath.